# Difference between 1 LSTM with num_layers = 2 and 2 LSTMs in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, pytorch

I am new to deep learning and currently working on using LSTMs for language modeling. I was looking at the pytorch documentation and was confused by it.

If I create a

```
nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)
```

where hidden_size = 4 and num_layers = 2, I think I will have an architecture something like:

```
op0    op1 ....
LSTM -> LSTM -> h3
LSTM -> LSTM -> h2
LSTM -> LSTM -> h1
LSTM -> LSTM -> h0
x0     x1 .....
```

If I do something like

```
nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, 1)
nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, 1)
```

I think the network architecture will look exactly like above. Am I wrong? And if yes, what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The multi-layer LSTM is better known as stacked LSTM where multiple layers of LSTM are stacked on top of each other.

Your understanding is correct. The following two definitions of stacked LSTM are same.

```
nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, 2)
```

and

```
nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
    ('LSTM1', nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, 1),
    ('LSTM2', nn.LSTM(hidden_size, hidden_size, 1)
]))
```

Here, the input is feed into the lowest layer of LSTM and then the output of the lowest layer is forwarded to the next layer and so on so forth. Please note, the output size of the lowest LSTM layer and the rest of the LSTM layer's input size is `hidden_size`.

However, you may have seen people defined stacked LSTM in the following way:

```
rnns = nn.ModuleList()
for i in range(nlayers):
    input_size = input_size if i == 0 else hidden_size
    rnns.append(nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, 1))
```

The reason people sometimes use the above approach is that if you create a stacked LSTM using the first two approaches, you can't get the hidden states of each individual layer. Check out what [LSTM](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/nn.html?highlight=lstm#torch.nn.LSTM) returns in PyTorch.

So, if you want to have the intermedia layer's hidden states, you have to declare each individual LSTM layer as a single LSTM and run through a loop to mimic the multi-layer LSTM operations. For example:

```
outputs = []
for i in range(nlayers):
    if i != 0:
        sent_variable = F.dropout(sent_variable, p=0.2, training=True)
    output, hidden = rnns[i](sent_variable)
    outputs.append(output)
    sent_variable = output
```

In the end, `outputs` will contain all the hidden states of each individual LSTM layer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do you know what could be the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: @user3828311 can you post another question on SO on that topic? I can answer it then.

Comment: Just wondered if you could clarify the term `outputs`? Does it include cell state as well or is it just hidden state?

Comment: To clarify, "the output of the lowest layer is forwarded to the next layer and so on so forth", it really means the hidden state from the previous layer (multiplied by `dropout`) is taken an input for the next layer, referring to the official doc.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear on the above (I guess I'm also asking a question here), I think the code below will NOT work. This is since the LSTM returns a pair `output, (hidden, cell)` but the input to the next layer needs to be `output` only. So, you need to capture that explicitly, as in a for loop.

```py
rnn = nn.Sequential(
  OrderedDict([
    ('rnn1', rnn1),
    ('rnn2', rnn2),
  ])
)
```